What does Krishna say in the Gita about deities other than himself?
https://shlokam.org/bhagavad-gita/9-25/#:~:text=Deva%2Dvratah%2C%20votaries%20of%20the,to%3B%20devan%2C%20the%20gods.

यान्ति देवव्रता देवान्पितॄन्यान्ति पितृव्रताः ।
भूतानि यान्ति भूतेज्या यान्ति मद्याजिनोऽपि माम् ॥ ९-२५॥


yānti devavratā devānpitṝnyānti pitṛvratāḥ
bhūtāni yānti bhūtejyā yānti madyājino’pi mām 9-25


The worshippers of the DEVAS or gods go to the DEVAS; to the PITRIS or ancestors go the ancestor-worshippers; to the BHUTAS or the elements go worshippers of the BHUTAS; but My worshippers come unto Me.

Krishna says or implies elsewhere in the Gita that he alone is Brahman - he is clearly saying here that worship of divinities other than himself leads to limited benefits. Is he saying that Devas, Bhutas et al are lower divinities?
My understanding is that only Vishnuist sects such as Madhwism have the notion of higher and lower divinities.

He means: Various prayers are meant for the intended gods but I am supreme above all the Bhutas, above all gods and all elements.


Is he saying that Devas, Bhutas et al are lower divinities?

Assuming that this is a question on the Bhagavad Gita alone, the below sloka from the Gita makes things clear.

na mē viduḥ suragaṇāḥ prabhavaṅ na maharṣayaḥ.|
ahamādirhi dēvānāṅ maharṣīṇāṅ ca sarvaśaḥ৷৷10.2৷৷

Neither the gods nor the great sages know My majesty. For, in all respects, I am the source of the gods and the great sages.

Yes, the Devas, Bhutas, and others are lower divinities compared to Lord Krishna.
This is explained by Krishna to Arjuna in detail in Chapter 7 (Jnana Vijnana Yoga - Knowledge of The Ultimate Truth). I've quoted a few verses below.
bahūnāṃ janmanāmante jñānavānmāṃ prapadyate
vāsudevaḥ sarvamiti sa mahātmā sudurlabhaḥ 7-19


At the end of many births the wise man comes to Me, realising that all
this is Vasudeva (the innermost Self); such a great soul (MAHATMA) is
very hard to find.

kāmaistaistairhṛtajñānāḥ prapadyante’nyadevatāḥ
taṃ taṃ niyamamāsthāya prakṛtyā niyatāḥ svayā 7-20


Those whose wisdom has been looted away by this or that desire, go to
other gods, following this or that rite, led by their own nature.

yo yo yāṃ yāṃ tanuṃ bhaktaḥ śraddhayārcitumicchati
tasya tasyācalāṃ śraddhāṃ tāmeva vidadhāmyaham 7-21


Whatsoever form any devotee desires to worship with faith — that
(same) faith of his I make (firm and) unflinching.

sa tayā śraddhayā yuktastasyārādhanamīhate
labhate ca tataḥ kāmānmayaiva vihitānhi tān 7-22

antavat tu phalaṁ teṣāṁ tad bhavaty alpa-medhasām
devān deva-yajo yānti mad-bhaktā yānti mām api


Endued with that faith, he engages in the worship of that DEVATA and
from it he obtains his desire-fulfilments; all these being ordained,
indeed, by Me (alone).

antavattu phalaṃ teṣāṃ tadbhavatyalpamedhasām
devāndevayajo yānti madbhaktā yānti māmapi 7-23


Men of small intelligence worship the DEVAS, and their fruits are
limited and temporary. Those who worship the DEVAS go to the planets
of the DEVAS, but My devotees ultimately reach My supreme planet.

